# Why are $\operatorname{Tor}_2$ and $\operatorname{Ext}^2$ often $0$?

Tags: functors, derived-functors

I'm doing a bunch of exercises involving the $\operatorname{Tor}$ and $\operatorname{Ext}$ functors and often the functors are non-trivial for $i = 0,1$ and become $0$ for $i \geq 2$. Why is this?

My intuition says that it is because the induced long exact sequence becomes exact after the first $\operatorname{Ext}^1$ or $\operatorname{Tor}_1$ term. Is this true?

Comment: In general, if $A$ is a quotient of a projective module by a projective submodule (for example if $A$ is a finitely generated module over a PID), then it has a projective resolution of length 1, so $\operatorname{Ext}^i(A,B)$ and $\operatorname{Tor}_i(A,B)$ are zero for $i\ge 2$ and any $B$.

Comment: Maybe also simply because the base ring in those exercises have global dimension  at most $1$?

Comment: This is kind of like asking, "why are primes often even?".  Of course they aren't really, but the even prime is one of the simplest and most important primes so you see it a lot.

Comment: It is most definitely because your ring is $\Bbb Z$, a field, or some other PID. Any module over a PID has a free resolution with only two nonzero terms, so the only possible nontrivial Ext/Tor groups are in degree $0$ and $1$

Comment: @mtheorylord, see Weibel's *An introduction to homological algebra*, section 3.1 (in particular 3.1.1, 3.1.2) and section 3.3 (in particular 3.3.1). Tor$_{n}$ and Ext vanish$^{n}$ vanish for $n\geq2$ on abelian groups.